# c# complex objects comparison

Tags: c#, ienumerable, except

```
public class SecurityMaster : EntityObject
     {
        public string BondIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
         public EntityCollection<SecurityMasterSchedules> SecurityMasterSchedules { get; set}
      }
     public class SecurityMasterSchedules :EntityObject
     {
           public string BondIdentifier { get; set; }
           public decimal rate { get; set; }
           public datetime startdate { get; set; }
           public datetime endate { get; set; }
     }
```

How do I compare the objects List list1 and List list2? IEnumerable except method doesn't work with complex objects.

```
   List<SecurityMaster> list1 = new List<SecurityMaster>();
   List<SecurityMaster> list2 = new List<SecurityMaster>();
```

Comment: In the code you supplied, I do not see list1, or list2, or the Except method.... please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have two `IEnumerable<EntityObject>` sequences and you want to know how to use `Except` in a way that treats two `EntityObjects` as identical under specific criteria. I'm going to further guess that these criteria comprise one simple rule (just to make life easier for myself in providing this answer): two items with the same `BondIdentifier` property will be considered identical.

Well, then, use the overload for `Except` that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>`:

```
class EntityObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<EntityObject>
{
    public bool Equals(EntityObject x, EntityObject y)
    {
        string xId = GetBondIdentifier(x);
        string yId = GetBondIdentifier(y);

        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    private string GetBondIdentifier(EntityObject obj)
    {
        var sm = obj as SecurityMaster;
        if (sm != null)
        {
            return sm.BondIdentifier;
        }

        var sms = obj as SecurityMasterSchedules;
        if (sms != null)
        {
            return sms.BondIdentifier;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

List<EntityObject> list1 = GetList1();
List<EntityObject> list2 = GetList2();

var itemsInList1NotInList2 = list1.Except(list2, new EntityObjectComparer());
```

Even if my guess as to the criteria was wrong, you can still use this answer as a basis from which to formulate your own.

If my initial guess was also wrong, then clearly this answer is useless to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your code has to do with anything, but here's how you use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
var list1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new int[] { 1 };

var output = list1.Except(list2).First();

Console.WriteLine(output);  // prints "2"
```