# How to compare two lists of the same complex type?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of a same complex type ie. class.

```
var list1 = new List<Info>();
list1.Add(new Info(){ A = 100, B = 100 });
list1.Add(new Info(){ A = 200, B = 200 });

var list2 = new List<Info>();
list2.Add(new Info(){ A = 20, B = 20 });
list2.Add(new Info(){ A = 200, B = 200 });

public class Info
{
        public int A {get;set;}
        public int B {get;set; }
}
```

When I do

```
list1.Except(list2);
```

I get a result which is incorrect. Obviously the results are showing all the items of List1.

```
{ A = 100, B = 100 }
{ A = 200, B = 200 }
```

When I use anonymous class for this same operation I get a correct result

```
list1.Select(a=> new { A = a.A, B = a.B}).Except(list2.Select(b=> new {A = b.A, B = b.B})).ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is not a duplicate questions, since the "original" question in unanswered and vaguely explained. Further more this questions introduces a possibility of comparing anonymous objects.

Comment: override Equals on the `Info` class.

Comment: In order for `Except` to determine that two elements are equal you have to indicate what "equals" means by **overriding** `Equals`, or alternativly - if you can´t change the `Info`-class - by providing an `IEqualityComparer<Info>`.

Comment: You get all elements of `list1` that does not exist in `list2`. The result is correct because the classes (`Info`) are compared by reference. So even though the values of the second `Info` in both lists are the same, they are different instances and are therefore not equal. You need to override the `Equals` method on the `Info` class to compare them the way you want.

Comment: Have a look at `Tuple`s esp. on *named tuples*

Comment: Really nice and informative answer on already answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526766/c-sharp-complex-objects-comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not overriding `Equals`/`GetHashCode` in your `Info` class hence there is no way for `Except` to determine equality between two given `Info` objects.

This works when you use [Anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

> Because the **Equals** and **GetHashCode** methods on anonymous types are
>   defined in terms of the **Equals** and **GetHashCode** methods of the
>   properties, **two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if
>   all their properties are equal**.

Comment: **This** is your answer? Pretty short, isn´t it? Only gives a vague idea of what is to be done.

Comment: @HimBromBeere well the question was "What am I doing wrong?"

Comment: When implementing `Equals` we have to implment `GetHashCode` as well

Comment: Why does anonymous object act differently?

Comment: @mko Because an anonymolus object is compared by comparing every member.

Comment: @HimBromBeere what do you mean by comparing every member?

Comment: @mko Well, there are not much members on an anonymous object, except its **properties** (and `Equals`  and `GetHashCode` inherited from `object`). In fact an anonymous object is nothing but a set of properties.

Comment: @HimBromBeere so is Equals and GetHashCode are inherited how come we dont need to override them for comparision to work?

Comment: @mko Because they are overriden in the compiled types. Sorry, I wasn´t too clear in my comment about this. See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types for further details.